# Laravel Sail with Github actions: How to run artisan and composer commands on container start

Tags: docker, docker-compose, github-actions, laravel-sail

I'm using Laravel sail and deploy the app on VPS using Github actions and need to know where should I run artisan and composer commands on container start. Is it here on Github actions file? (the last 3 commands) `docker exec -it laravel9-dashboard-laravel-1 bash` (to gain access to the container), `php artisan optimize:clear`, `composer dump-autoload`

```
# Article: https://medium.com/rockedscience/docker-ci-cd-pipeline-with-github-actions-6d4cd1731030
name: Build and push Docker image upon release

on:
  # Build and push Docker images *only* for releases.
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  run-linters:
    name: Run linters
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Check out Git repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up PHP
        uses: shivammathur/setup-php@v2
        with:
          php-version: "8.1"
          coverage: none
          tools: phpcs

      - name: Run linters
        uses: wearerequired/lint-action@v2
        with:
          php_codesniffer: true
          # Optional: Ignore warnings
          php_codesniffer_args: "-n"
  ssh:
    name: Build SSH
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: executing remote ssh commands using password
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.VULTR_HOST }}
          username: ${{ secrets.VULTR_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.VULTR_PASSWORD }}
          port: ${{ secrets.VULTR_PORT }}
          script: |
            cd laravel9-dashboard
            docker-compose down
            docker container prune -y
            git pull origin main
            docker build -t laravel9-dashboard . --no-cache
            docker-compose up -d --remove-orphans
            docker exec -it laravel9-dashboard-laravel-1 bash
            php artisan optimize:clear
            composer dump-autoload
```

Or should I add these commands in Docker file

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

LABEL maintainer="Taylor Otwell"

ARG NODE_VERSION=16
ARG POSTGRES_VERSION=14

WORKDIR /var/www/html

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV TZ=UTC

RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y cron \
    && apt-get install -y gnupg gosu curl ca-certificates zip unzip git supervisor sqlite3 libcap2-bin libpng-dev python2 \
    && mkdir -p ~/.gnupg \
    && chmod 600 ~/.gnupg \
    && echo "disable-ipv6" >> ~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf \
    && echo "keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80" >> ~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf \
    && gpg --recv-key 0x14aa40ec0831756756d7f66c4f4ea0aae5267a6c \
    && gpg --export 0x14aa40ec0831756756d7f66c4f4ea0aae5267a6c > /usr/share/keyrings/ppa_ondrej_php.gpg \
    && echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ppa_ondrej_php.gpg] https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu jammy main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ppa_ondrej_php.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y php8.1-cli php8.1-dev \
       php8.1-pgsql php8.1-sqlite3 php8.1-gd \
       php8.1-curl \
       php8.1-imap php8.1-mysql php8.1-mbstring \
       php8.1-xml php8.1-zip php8.1-bcmath php8.1-soap \
       php8.1-intl php8.1-readline \
       php8.1-ldap \
       php8.1-msgpack php8.1-igbinary php8.1-redis php8.1-swoole \
       php8.1-memcached php8.1-pcov php8.1-xdebug \
    && php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer \
    && curl -sLS https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_$NODE_VERSION.x | bash - \
    && apt-get install -y nodejs \
    && npm install -g npm \
    && curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | gpg --dearmor | tee /usr/share/keyrings/yarn.gpg >/dev/null \
    && echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/yarn.gpg] https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list \
    && curl -sS https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | gpg --dearmor | tee /usr/share/keyrings/pgdg.gpg >/dev/null \
    && echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/pgdg.gpg] http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt jammy-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y yarn \
    && apt-get install -y mysql-client \
    && apt-get install -y postgresql-client-$POSTGRES_VERSION \
    && apt-get -y autoremove \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

RUN setcap "cap_net_bind_service=+ep" /usr/bin/php8.1

RUN groupadd --force -g 1000 sail
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash --no-user-group -g 1000 -u 1337 sail

COPY scheduler /etc/cron.d/scheduler
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/scheduler \
    && crontab /etc/cron.d/scheduler

COPY start-container /usr/local/bin/start-container
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
COPY php.ini /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/99-sail.ini
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/start-container

EXPOSE 8000

ENTRYPOINT ["start-container"]
```

I'm not Docker expert I'm just trying to learn what I need to deploy my app using Docker and Github actions

Comment: Would the approach described in [this thread](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/code-review/unable-to-install-sail-into-existing-app?page=1&replyId=778296) be of any help?